# How do I calculate the collector voltage of transistors Q1 and Q2 in this constant current circuit?

Tags: voltage, circuit-analysis, dc, constant-current

[image: http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/134sfc.pdf]
[Source](http://cds.linear.com/docs/en/datasheet/134sfc.pdf)

What I know (I think):
Q1 and Q2 are PNP transistors.
A1 is a differential amplifier.
When A1's output is low, current through Q1 and Q2 is increased.
The Q1 and Q2 collector voltage must be less than the A1 output voltage.

How do I calculate the collector voltage of transistors Q1 and Q2 in this constant current circuit?

Comment: National Semi, the original design/manufacturer of the lm134 has a better datasheet (now ti) http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/lm334.pdf

Comment: When in linear regulation \$V_{C,1}\$ = V- and \$V_{C,2}\$ = V- + 64 mV (at roomtemp, voltage ref is deltaVbe derived and hence PTAT)